# spring hibernate.createSQLQuery return as custom entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring

I am doing `Query query = hibernate.createSQLQuery("select abc,def from table");`

Is it possible to auto "parse" the result to "POJO" list?

So that I can do this:

```
List<CustomPOJO> abc = query.list();    //CustomPOJO is pojo not entity , no @Entity tag
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
hibernate.createSQLQuery("select abc,def from table").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CustomPOJO.class));
```

like the [reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904) suggests.