# store map in list using hibernate createSQLQuery method

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate's createSQLQuery method to return a list.

code:

```
Query query=session.createSQLQuery("select name,marks,grade from student where id=12");
List list = query.list();
```

Also I want to know what will be returned in list. Will it contain just values or will it also contain column name.

If it also contain column name, then I want to break every element of this list to col name and its value; so that i can put Map`<String,String>` (Map`<colName,colValue>`) to a new list `List<Map<String,String>>` How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

createSQLQuery returns

```
List<Object[]>
```

, it will contain just values. 
You can extract it as you like, for example

```
    List<Map<String,String>> = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();  
    for (Object row: queryResult)
                    {
                        Map <String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Object[] versionId = (Object [])row;
                        map.put("name", versionId[0]);
                        ... 
                        result.add(map);
                    }
```

Or you can create a model and transer query Result to list of entities look here [spring hibernate.createSQLQuery return as custom entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183393/spring-hibernate-createsqlquery-return-as-custom-entity)

Comment: Also, to get a `List<Map<columnName, columnValue>>` you can use `createSQLQuery(...).setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)`